# How to get an explanatory string from std::regex_error?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, error-handling

My program is throwing an `std::regex_error()`. I'd like to know what the error is, since the regex looks legit to me. I did essentially this:

```
try {
    // offending code
} catch (std::regex_error& e) {
    log_error("Regex error: " << e.what() << ", " << e.code());
}
```

The output is:

```
Regex error: regex_error, 4
```

This isn't particularly helpful. What does 4 mean? The [en.cppreference.com entry for code()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_error/code) only says:

> Returns the std::regex_constants::error_type that was passed to the std::regex_error constructor.

The entry for [error_type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/error_type) gives a list of error codes, all of whose exact values are "unspecified".

Do I have no recourse but to do something like this?

```
switch (e.code()) {
    case std::regex_constants::error_collate: return "error_collate";
    case std::regex_constants::error_ctype: return "error_ctype";
    // etc ...
}
```

Comment: If you're using the gnu implementation of the standard c++ library, 4 is a bracket error. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc742814f2027097

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a quality-of-implementation issue in the standard C++ library, which is a nice way of saying that it's a bug. [GCC bug 67361](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67361), to be exact ("std::regex_error::what() should say something about the error_code").

There is a recently submitted patch in the bug report, so I suppose that it will eventually show up as an upgrade. [**Update:** According to the bug report above, it was fixed in v6.1 (released April 26, 2016) but the bug report was not marked as resolved until November 19, 2018. Anyway, if you have a reasonably recent distribution, this should not be a problem any more.]

In the meantime, you have little option but to roll your own code->message conversion function. (Or, as an interim debugging method, consult `include/bits/regex_error.h`)

Comment: This saddens me greatly! I've taken the approach of consulting `regex_error.h` for the nonce.

Comment: @Claudiu: Indeed. Although it would be sadder if there wasn't a fix in trunk (in which case, I might have suggested using the LLVM project's [libc++ implementation](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/src/regex.cpp?revision=214201&view=markup).)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using the `switch` is to define your own enum for each regex error code and cast the result to that, giving you better runtime debugging aid.

```
enum class RegexError {
    collate = std::regex_constants::error_collate,
    ctype   = std::regex_constants::error_ctype,
    // etc
};

RegexError errorCode = static_cast<RegexError>( e.code() );
// your debugger will now show you what the meaning of errorCode is
```

That way you don't need to use strings.

However, if you want to display the error to the user in a human-readable fashion then you will need to use strings, but you can use a map to store them:

```
map<RegexError, wchar_t const * const> errorMessages;
errorMessages[RegexError::collate] = L"the expression contains an invalid collating element name";
errorMessages[RegexError::ctype  ] = L"the expression contains an invalid character class name";
// etc
```